# Is it possible to test a sequence of asynchronous function calls with D.O.H

Tags: javascript, testing, dojo, doh

I am trying to use [doh.Deferred](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-4-meta-dojo/d-o-h-unit-testing) to write a test that will check the following sequence of events:

1. login with user A (asynchronous)
2. log out (synchronous)
3. login with user A (asynchronous)

The return value of the second callback function is another doh.Deferred object.  I was under the impression that the callback chain of d will wait for d2 but it does not.  The test finishes before d2.callback is ever called.

Where am I going wrong here?

Does anyone know of a better way for me to test this behavior?

```
function test() {
    var d = new doh.Deferred();

    d.addCallback(function() {  
        Comm.logout(); /* synchronus */
        try {   
            // check with doh.t and doh.is
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            d.errback(e);
        }
    });

    d.addCallback(function() {
        var d2 = new dojo.Deferred();
        /* asynchronus - third parameter is a callback */
        Comm.login('alex', 'asdf', function(result, msg) {
                try {
                    // check with doh.t and doh.is
                    d2.callback(true);
                } catch (e) {
                    d2.errback(e);
                }                   
            });
        return d2; // returning doh.Defferred -- expect d to wait for d2.callback
    });     

    /* asynchronus - third parameter is a callback */
    Comm.login('larry', '123', function (result, msg) {
        try {
            // check with doh.t and doh.is 
            d.callback(true);
        } catch (e) {
            d.errback(e);
        }
    }); 

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  The scope of d2 was the problem.

```
function test() {
    var d = new doh.Deferred();
    var d2 = new doh.Deferred();

    d.addCallback(function() {  
        Comm.logout(); /* synchronus */
        try {   
                // check with doh.t and doh.is
                return true;
        } catch (e) {
                d.errback(e);
        }
    });

    d.addCallback(function() {
        /* asynchronus - third parameter is a callback */
        Comm.login('alex', 'asdf', function(result, msg) {
                        try {
                                // check with doh.t and doh.is
                                d2.callback(true);
                        } catch (e) {
                                d2.errback(e);
                        }                                       
                });
        return d2; // returning doh.Deferred -- waits for d2.callback
    });         

    /* asynchronus - third parameter is a callback */
    Comm.login('larry', '123', function (result, msg) {
        try {
                // check with doh.t and doh.is 
                d.callback(true);
        } catch (e) {
                d.errback(e);
        }
    }); 

    return d;
}
```